# React Router returns child components and not parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react router to implemented nested routes.

In my App.js, the Routes look like this:

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/myplan" component={MyPlan} />
        <Route path="/myplan/financial-planning/:topicId" component={CollegeExpenses} />
        <Route path="/myplan/:topicId" component={FinancialPlanning} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

It can render the /home route perfectly (includes sidebar, header, and background color) whether you click the back or forward button. However, if you were to click back to /myplan (or any other link besides /home), it would only render whatever I coded within that file and not the sidebar, header, or background color.

My Dashboard.jsx file looks like this.

```
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', height: '100vh' }}>
    //top bar
      <section className={classes.header}>
        <form className={classes.form}>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-size-small"
            label="Search for lesson"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
          />
          <IconButton type="submit" className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="search">
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </form>
        <div className={classes.user}>
          <IconButton >
            <Avatar fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </section>
      //sidebar
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Router>

          <section className={classes.sidebar}>
            <div className={classes.logo}>
              <img src={logo} alt="Imagication" className={classes.logoBtn} />
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
              <nav className={classes.nav}>

                <IconButton className={classes.navBtn} component={Link} to="/home" style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)" }} >
                  <Tooltip title="Home" className={classes.toolTip}>
                    <HomeIcon />
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton className={classes.navBtn} component={Link} to="/myplan" style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)" }}>
                  <Tooltip className={classes.toolTip} title="My Plan" >
                    <Map />
                  </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
              </nav>
            </div>

          </section>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <Switch >
              <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/myplan" component={MyPlan} />
              <Route path="/myplan/financial-planning/:topicId" component={CollegeExpenses} />
              <Route path="/myplan/:topicId" component={FinancialPlanning} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div >
```

I am able to click a button that will take me from /home to /myplan as well as /home to /myplan/financial-planning.

Let's say I am on /myplan/financial-planning/college-expenses and want to return to /myplan/financial-planning, it will only render whatever I coded within that specific file and not the sidebar or header.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you make your example smaller -- shrink the app until everything not related ot the problem is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your code, I see a little bit of confusion regarding how you plan to structure the routes,

If you want Dashboard and MyPlan to be on two separate routes, meaning they are accessible on routes `/dashboard` and `/myplan`, I don't think it's possible to share sections of `Dashboard` (like Header, Sidebar) with MyPlan.

You Could do that manually, By creating a Sidebar or Header component and do something like this in `App.js`

```
   <Route  path="/home">
     <Header/>
     <SideBar/>
     <Dashboard/>
   </Route>
   <Route exact path="/myplan" >
     <Header/>
     <SideBar/>
     <MyPlan/>
   </Route>
```

If you don't want to insert header or sidebar manually, and you want to use Switch instead, like you have done already, you need to use **Nested Routing**

first, remove any other routes other than Home in App.js

```
   <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
</Router>
```

In Dashboard:

```
    let { path } = useRouteMatch();

        return (
         <div>
         //  ... Implementations of Sidebar and Header, no more <Router> needed
        <Switch >
          <Route exact path={`${path}/myplan`} component={MyPlan} />
          <Route path={`${path}/myplan/financial-planning/:topicId`}  component= 
           {CollegeExpenses} />
          <Route path={`${path}/myplan/:topicId`} component={FinancialPlanning} />
        </Switch>
```